# asp.net mvc5 fullcalendar end parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm making a asp.net mvc program using fullcalendar
It works fine only except 'end' factor.
It caused 'end' is reserved word at query.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //defaultDate: '2015-04-09',
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'title'
                },
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                selectable: true,
                events: '/Home/GetEvents'
});


public class Task
{
   public int id { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }

        public string start { get; set; }

        public string endtime { get; set; }
}


public List<Task> GetAll()
{
    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();

    TaskList = this._db.Query<Task>(
            @"SELECT TaskId id
                 , TaskNm title
                 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskFrom, 120) start
                 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskTo, 120) endtime
              FROM dbo.Task").ToList();

            return TaskList;
}

public ActionResult GetEvents()
{
     var taskList = taskrepository.GetAll();            

     return Json(taskList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I changed 'end' to 'endtime' to prevent using reserved word but it doesn't work.
Is there any method to make it works? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable with reserved word using @ symbol. So make it @end it should work.

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [end], 120) [end]
It works well. Thanks for remind